# Using GPU with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, keras

i'm actally facing a probleme since last friday and didn't find a solution for the moment.

First of all, you need to know that i'm a beginner on linux,i'm trying to do some deep learning in my internship, and i discovered that even if my company have a 1080 Ti, keras wasn't using it, so have the job to correct this.

I am trying to use Keras with GPU. I installer Tensorflow by following these steps : https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux
I also installer CUDA,cuDNN.

I found on my machine an older installation of CUDA (version 7.5). I installed version 9.2 without uninstalling version 7.5. I added the PATH variables but it seems like it is not taking in account : [][https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3Pqm.png]

I tried to uninstall CUDA version 7.5 but i don't know how to do it, since in the usr/local folder, there is no cuda-7.5 folder.

When i enter nvidia-smi in the prompt, it works correctly. I installed tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu, but i does not work :  [][https://i.stack.imgur.com/78gPd.png]

Did anyone know how to help me? i Guess the solution of my probleme is not really complicated for someone who knows Ubuntu, and i feel like i'm loosing a lot of times doing something i don't really understand.

If someone need some further informations in order to help me, feel free to ask.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall tensorflow and install only tensorflow-gpu. You should not install both. If you are using keras, then install keras-gpu.

Let's say you are working with conda and you want to tidy up all this. Do

```
conda remove keras
conda remove tensorflow*
conda install keras-gpu
```

If you are not, then i highly recommend [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python) for dealing with these issues which you seem to be having stress-free.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I followed your instructions. I am using pip and pio don't work for installing keras-gpu. I tried with conda and it worked.

but, when i launch python and try to import keras, i got the following message : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.framework'

For my second probleme(my computer use the version 7.5 of CUDA but i installed version 9.2) i found a solution by changing some environnement variables. i checked and cuDNN seems to be here and to work correctly (tested with the samples).

Comment: Did you delete the pip installations first? That would be a good step. So do 'pip uninstall tensorflow' and repeat for other modules that might be conflicting. For instance tensorflow-gpu and keras. Also, there is a chance you installed things for the user and the user as su as well. So i would also do 'sudo pip uninstall tensorflow', just in case.

Comment: I deleted tensorflow and keras with pip. then i tried a pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu, and then it worked ! Now my training is taking 2 mins/epoch instead of 23 mins. I still didn't really understand why it worked but nevermind. Thank you for Help !

Comment: Great. Could you accept this answer please in that case?